# Как найти дубликаты и удалить их в коллекции безопасно?

Tags: java

Как найти дубликаты и удалить их в коллекции безопасно?

У меня есть `List` из элементов "A" "A" "B" "A".

Значения я не знаю какие. Мне надо дубликаты удалить.

Я попробовал добавить `list` в `LinkedHasSet`, эффекта ноль.

`Class Recipe`, внутри есть переменная `String`. `Comparable` уже подключил. Все равно `LinkedHasSet` не удаляет дублирующие элементы

Это класс Recipe:

```
public class Recipe implements Parent<Course>,Comparable<Recipe>{
    @SerializedName("listCourse") public List<Course> course;
    @SerializedName("namelists") public String nameLists="";

    public Recipe() {

    }

    @Override
    public List<Course> getChildList() {
        return course;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInitiallyExpanded() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Recipe recipe) {
        return nameLists.length()-recipe.nameLists.length();
    }
}
```

Код в MainActivity:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coursesTemps.size(); i++) {
            Recipe recipe=new Recipe();
            recipe.nameLists=coursesTemps.get(i).getTitle();
            recipe.course=coursesTemps.get(i).getCourses();

            if (recipe.getChildList().size()>0){
                linkedHashSet.add(recipe);
            }
        }

        recipes.addAll(linkedHashSet);

recipes = List;  
linkedHashSet=LinkedHasSet
```

Comment: какого типа данные?

Comment: Что значит "безопасно"? Причём тут `Comparable`? Что за класс `Recipe` и почему вы его не показываете? Как именно вы пытаетесь работать с LinkedHasSet? Что значит "Я попробовал добавить list в LinkedHasSet" ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Обновил вопрос. Таким образом даже если я использую LinkedHashSet то все равно я получаю дубликаты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в первую очередь переопределить equals и hash в классе. после использовать hashSet. Всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Перенести все элементы в set? Я так понимаю если вопрос стоит о коллекциях ,то вид коллекции значения не имеет?

Если важен именно лист, то вот сложный алгоритм (первый который пришел в голову):

-collections.frequency получить количество дубликатов и вычесть 1
- пройтись по листу циклом i